# Prove by Mean Value Theorem for $\arcsin$

Tags: calculus

I know how to do it by taking the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ and using it to prove by MVT but what bothers me with this is that why the exercise specifies the values of $y$, can someone give an advice or a simple hint with this one
$$
  x-y < \arcsin(x) - \arcsin(y) < 2(x-y) \quad\mathrm{if}\quad-\frac{3}{5}<y<\frac{3}{5}
$$

Comment: dont the slope $arcsin(x)$ blow up for $x$ near $ \pm 1?$

Comment: so this means that x must be between (3/5;1)?

Comment: you don't want to be near $\pm 1$  you want to stay way from it.

Comment: but x must be larger than 3/5

Comment: or the exercise can mean that -3/5<y<x<3/5

Comment: right? Is this right?

Comment: i am writing an answer. i will post in a minute.

Comment: ok thanks man I am really confused

Answer (score 1):

the the absolute value of the slope of $y = \sin^{-1} x$ is between $\frac 5 4$ and $1$ for $-3/5 \le x \le 3/5.$  by mean value theorem, $|\sin^{-1} x_1 - \sin^{-1}x_2| =  |slope| |x_1 - x_2|$

now that $1 < |slope| \le \frac 54 $ implies $ 1 < |x_1-x_2| < 2|x_1 - x_2|.$

the lower bound for the slope occurs at $x = 0$ and the upper bound at $x = \pm \frac 35$ where the slope is reciprocal of the cosine which is $\frac 45$

Comment: so by knowing that x1-x2 is smaller than 1 why get this result?

Comment: @user224677, the one comes from the smallest slope of $arcsin(x)$ at $x = 0$

Comment: yeah sorry i got it now